double-nesting map-reduce in LangGraph
I'm trying to use the fan-out and collapse-back pattern outlined here in this map-reduce example: https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/how-tos/map-reduce/
The problem is, I'm writing x lectures in a course and each lecture has y paragraphs. To do a transformation on each paragraph, I need to map over all the lectures and execute a subgraph. Within each one, I need to map over all the paragraphs and execute a sub-subgraph. I'm using the Send object because I don't know ahead of time what x or y will be.
This double-nesting appears to be causing strange behavior. It seems like the graph is losing track of which graph it's supposed to be sending to. It's trying to enter the sub-subgraph and throwing an error relating to the outermost graph.
Is this level of nesting with Send currently unsupported?

can you make a toy example?
